# Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'PaintingBinding' which excludes null

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I am trying to build my flutter project in android studio,
Note that I did not use fade Duration in this project

and I have this problem when I upgrade flutter and android studio

The issue :

```
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/overlay.dart:195:24: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('/D:/src1/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
      SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback(_markNeedsBuild);
                       ^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/handle_overlay.dart:60:40: Error: Member not found: 'fadeDuration'.
        duration: TextSelectionOverlay.fadeDuration, vsync: this);
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'D:\src1\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1148

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'D:\src1\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 51s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: close your IDE then open and try running your code

Comment: Try 'flutter pub cache repair' @Fadi hadded

Comment: hi, Have you found a solution to this problem?
i have this problem too

Answer (score 1):

The lib `flutter_math_fork-0.5.0` may be used on the another library, but the flutter latest not support the method `TextSelectionOverlay.fadeDuration`
You just override the newer version of `flutter_math_fork` on `pubspec.yaml`

Example:

```dart
dependency_overrides:
  flutter_math_fork: ^0.6.1
```